# Como começar com WebRTC, estou perdida

Tags: javascript, webrtc

Eu preciso desenvolver um projetinho simples: ligação entre pontos que compartilhem vídeo e áudio (vídeo chamada no caso), simples, apenas na teoria.

Eu comecei a pesquisar sobre o assunto e estou completamente perdida, existe `peerjs`, existe `webrtc`, existe milhares de bibliotecas e eu não sei qual é a melhor/segura, simplesmente não sei por onde começar.

Gostaria de fazer com código puro mas não sei se é viável ou se tem como.

Comment: Conheço o [http://webrtc2sip.org/](http://webrtc2sip.org/) já usei para fazer conversas de áudio e vídeo entre navegador/telefone e navegador/navegador usando o protocolo SIP.

Answer (score 1):

Você até pode utilizar WebRTC com a API "pura", recomendo esse tutorial em inglês: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/basics/

Mas eu achei mais fácil usar as bibliotecas disponíveis em https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/

Lá tem vários exemplos, para fazer vídeo chamada com som, compartilhar tela, chat de texto e etc, como esse aqui que é um dos mais completos: https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/RTCMultiConnection/MultiRTC/

Geralmente é bem simples, só incluir alguns arquivos javascript, copiar algumas chamadas e funciona.

Para criar um canal de comunicação utilizando a biblioteca RTCMultiConnection, você deve fazer algo como:

```
var connection = new RTCMultiConnection();
connection.firebase = false;

connection.session = {
    audio: true,
    video: true
};
var current_user = 'test user';
```

Para criaçao de "salas" para video conferência, é utilizado um "servidor de sinalização", você pode ler mais sobre isso em: https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/blob/master/Signaling.md

Abaixo está um exemplo de código que inicia a conexão com um servidor de sinalização utilizando WebSockets (mas você pode usar o FireBase, ou mesmo TUN/STUN ou outros protocolos com pouca variação, como é descrito no link acima):

```
connection.openSignalingChannel = function(config) {

    var channel = location.href.replace(/\/|:|#|%|\.|\[|\]/g, '');
    var websocket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost");
    websocket.channel = channel;

    websocket.onopen = function () {
            websocket.push(JSON.stringify({
                    open: true,
                    channel: channel
            }));
            if (config.callback) {
                config.callback(websocket);
            }

    };
    websocket.onmessage = function(event) {
        config.onmessage(JSON.parse(event.data));
    };
    websocket.push = websocket.send;
    websocket.send = function (data) {
            if (websocket.readyState != 1) {
                    return setTimeout(function() {
                            websocket.send(data);
                    }, 300);
            }

            websocket.push(JSON.stringify({
                    data: data,
                    channel: channel
            }));
    };
    return websocket;
};
```

Existem alguns outros eventos que você deve implementar conforme os exemplos e conforme você pode ver em: https://github.com/danielneis/moodle-mod_webrtcexperiments/blob/master/module.js#L11

No final você deve lembrar de fazer a conexão propriamente dita, executando:

```
connection.connect();
```

Comment: Olá, Daniel. Seja bem vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português.
O SO tem uma política de que as respostas não devem basear-se somente em links. Saiba mais aqui: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/42/queremos-respostas-que-contenham-somente-links

Comment: Mas o Daniel apresentou código de exemplo também, não foi apenas baseados em links.